# phpmyadmin 3.4.x drop/empty table tabs removed

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've just updated to phpmyadmin 3.4.6 and I just realized that the drop/empty tabs are being removed and put under the operations tab.
Is there an option to enable those tabs again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at

http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/phpMyAdmin-Changelog-3359.html

- Move drop/empty links from being tabs to Operations tab.

Its a change that done from phpMyAdmin 3.4.0

If you wanna do what you want you have to use older versions :-(

Comment: are you yet searching for an option ?